# useReducer's initialState is typed as never?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

initialState has the error: **Argument of type '{ email: string; password: string; valid: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)**

```
function reducer(state: IState, action: IFluxAction) {
  const Users = UsersFetch()
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'email':
      const email = action.value
      const valid = Users.find(e => e === email) ? true : false

      return {
        email,
        valid,
      }
    case 'password':
      const password = action.value
      return {
        password,
      }
    default:
      throw new Error()
  }
}
```

```
  const initialState = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    valid: false,
  }
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState)
```

What's the proper way of typing this to satisfy the error?

**React 16.8.1**
**Typescript 3.3.1**

**Should be (is fixed by)**
adding `...state` to the returns, like

```
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'email':
      const email = action.value
      const valid = Users.find(e => e === email) ? true : false

      return {
        ...state,
        email,
        valid,
      }
    case 'password':
      const password = action.value
      return {
        ...state,
        password,
      }
    default:
      throw new Error()
  }
```

Additionally - as suggested by @madflanderz , setting IState as the reducer's expected return value helps catch issues like this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The issue is most likely with your reducer's declaration. The `initialState`'s type **must** be the same as the state's type and return value in the reducer function.

This will work:

```
function reducer(state: {email: string}) {
  return state
}
const initialState = {
  email: '',
}
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState)
```

This will produce an error:

```
// state has a different type than initialState.
function reducer(state: {address: string}) {
  // No return statement.
}
const initialState = {
  email: '',
}
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState) // Error
```

In the React's typing [you can see](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L811) that the `useReducer` generic function always expects the `initialState` type to be of a `ReducerState<R>` type. [The `ReducerState<R>`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L780) is a [conditional type](http://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) that tries to infer the proper state's type and falls back to `never` if it fails.

Comment: This is unfortunate.. The redux-starter-kit uses immer.js, and you're supposed to either mutate the state or return a new one, but never mix. I thought I'd go with mutation for a change, but that leads to this problem.. (See https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/api/createreducer last paragraph)

Answer (score 107):

I also struggled with this problem. The best way to prevent bugs seems to me to add the State Interface as the return type of the reducer. Then you see the type errors inside the reducer instead on the useReducer line.

like this:

```
function reducer(state: IState, action: IFluxAction): IState {
   // reducer code
   // type errors are visible here 
}
```

Comment: This helped to find out what was the incorrect returned state in switch block, Thanks

Comment: This really helps to figure out the problem. ESLint fails if there isn't any return type for the reducer and shows error at all functions (actions/usereducers) which involves reducer as it thinks return type is `never`

Comment: This is it. In my case, I had failed to add the return type. Once I added it, the issue was clear in the reducer.

Comment: This also helped me discover that the actual error was incorrect returned state in the switch block.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks, madflanderz!

I had the same issue. In my case, the problem was that I missed to type the return value of the reducer:

```
function reducer(state: IState, action: IFluxAction): IState /<- *Don't forget this!*/ {
   // reducer code
   // type errors are visible here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The object that holds your data.

```
export interfaace IObject {
    object: IObject
}
```

The state you are using to monitor it.

```
export interface IObjectState {
  
}
```

The actions that can be performed.

```
export interface IObjectActions {
    state: IObjectState
    payload: IObject
}
```

The reducer.

```
const reducer = (state: IObjectState, action: IObjectAction) => {
...return state
};
```

Remember that IObject and IObjectState are 2 different interfaces. From you error it would appear without the full code that you are attempting to pass a default 'IObject' in the reducers first parameter. When you should be correctly passing a default 'IObjectState'. I will attempt crudely to illustrate below.

Error: passing default value as IObject here

```
                         ↓
const reducer = (state: IObjectState, action: IObjectAction) => {
...return state
};
```

Correct: passing default IObjectState here

```
                         ↓
const reducer = (state: IObjectState, action: IObjectAction) => {
...return state
};
```

Hope this helps.