# Typescript: '{ translatedSentences: never[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I know similar questions have been asked on stackoverflow, and I have been reading through them and trying to implement their solutions. But, after over an hour of trying to change a million different things I am no closer to understanding this problem or how to solve it.

I am trying to add types to my reducer and I'm getting nowhere with this error:

[image]

**InitialState**

```
export const initialState = {
  activeStep: 0,
  notification: {
    format: undefined,
    message: "",
  },
  lesson: {
    title: "",
    language: { language: "", code: "" },
    topics: [],
    format: "",
    url: "",
    file: EMPTY_FILE,
    totalPoints: 0,
    totalWords: 0,
  },
  newWords: [],
  initialTranscript: [],
  modifiedTranscript: [],
  transcriptSentences: [],
  translatedSentences: [],
};
```

**Reducer**

```
export const reducer = (state: InitialState = initialState, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...

    case ActionTypes.SET_SENTENCE_TRANSLATIONS:
      return {
        ...state,
        translatedSentences: action.payload,
      };
    case ActionTypes.SET_SENTENCE_TRANSLATION:
      const { sentence, id } = action.payload;
      const translatedSentencesClone = state.translatedSentences.slice();
      translatedSentencesClone[id] = sentence;
      return {
        ...state,
        translatedSentences: translatedSentencesClone,
      };

    ...

  }
}
```

**Types**

```
export type TranslatedSentence = {
  id: number;
  source: string;
  translation: string;
  approved?: boolean;
};


// for the initial batch of all translations
interface SET_SENTENCE_TRANSLATIONS {
  type: ActionTypes.SET_SENTENCE_TRANSLATIONS;
  payload: TranslatedSentence[];
}

// for updating one translations
interface SET_SENTENCE_TRANSLATION {
  type: ActionTypes.SET_SENTENCE_TRANSLATION;
  payload: { sentence: TranslatedSentence; id: number };
}
```

Hopefully thats enough material, if not let me know. I'm stumped and feel pretty lost at this point.

Comment: If you are getting an inferred `never`, you've written code where TypeScript thinks it cannot have a value in that code.

Comment: I suspect it's due to this: `reducer = (state: InitialState ....`.  A reducer is a function which takes a `State` and an `Action` and returns a `State`.  So the type for the `state` argument should be the type of any valid state, not just the type of the initial state.  I can't debug further without seeing the interface/type `InitialState`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I actually just resolved it (at least it seems so, feel nervous making that statement), but essentially i found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771003/usereducers-initialstate-is-typed-as-never. Typing the return of the reducer helped me get _significantly_ better error messages `const reducer = (...) : InitialState => {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to leave another comment, but the [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2&ssl=52&ssc=71&pln=52&pc=76#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmAlNATJBjNKAXzgDMoIQ4AiKNAQzxmoG4BYAKE7QA9JY4eCADsU8YMOAxg9ADYBlGPRho4AXkSc4cRtIBuaRWjAAuOAAYANFrjCI00sDzLgIswhvbS0EMrNJhbDRHYRxrDm1tEDQUFHoAczQzampw7SI0uFkYlDdNCMjpGGzk1M8s%20mF4pASkxAqqmsTSy0EIINK4DPKYCDAnFDMAbQBdTK8fPxoygu0kKFkW8scS6fG4XqVZAAUICRhBi3XNuQB1aGxDqxtugtCAd3OoS%20GxmwkpGVkAFShKlDwUGAYBgr0yIHawEcOF%20-0BwNBcFGmRgf1E8JB8jQwhUwgIh2RNlR-1kyhwWJx2PxYM4RHYXA4%200IpEYqkUZPykQ2aJQpJU2ApuOpcFhoj55OxQrQo3pRE43D40HgMAAnmBVKLeWSBZKqaoNB4CsBsGZhEgQAAjQj07S5eYEMxiIFVG3ckkuPJOiTxV30MBgCgGbAAfjMFogEGylVl9PlHAA9PGyNANgALVQfaRyOAW5R4VNwCCkHSyWRusUe0ScJlQFkEODyACi3wA%20k2AHLfRvtgDCjZb3wwAEF2-IADJD74ASQA8qPORs1XVqE3Wx2u73%204OR%20PJ7PR6wbGB6CrZBB6CaRTzxTrKXjpSNZXHE8moHAkGBsC4qoXQuWtdIIgoNWlK1qyDbNm23Ybn2A7DqOE7TnOC6quqySrlBnbdrB24IXuc6HgUx6nuel4IHA6B3g6V7uvygp6iwcDGqa5pWm%20dK0nGqGqEOTCuMI6gQWu0HYVu8G7kh7ZwAAPkJmEwWJO6Ifu8ixhwvD8PAQiiPAdC4AQb4aAAFGIZJmOyKiCZmXwWWgrS6PxZi8YBwgAJTmUollqAAfAuKD3FI%20ZwEZDkiAAdNxrn5OUzjoDQGHrqJcFKfhB4mOU2h0DA8wCYaXJcmFhWmSo6xcsSFZ0bq96HKFwhhcRZ4XqVXSutosWqCukGJZuyV4ZJ1DpbMkTaWI9SUVKrTGl0gm1fVJ6NdgrXDUByrXtq9HVT2Z5-hoxVoBFa2VVRMRhbyThoEZrlLdo5UARKx0oFtIjSsaIyCeNDEZXAWU5Qu%20VwIVp2eXZX03Yd91Soct03ht%20JPaEzUcQy6ScQyI3wAAqmAC3bLUgmXeovl5ctOlIntrTYMAKDHjA%20ZvRoqCYDg%20CEEZ33MwZk2SFmCjA3AV20kAA) is too long to include.

What you want is for your reducer to take a `State` and an `Action` and return a `State` of the same type as the input.

Your `initialState` variable should fulfill your `State` interface, but so should any other valid state.  You will get errors if you use `typeof initialState` to create the `State` interface because this says that the property `translatedSentances` can only be an empty array aka `never[]`.  I haven't seen the definition of your type `InitialState`, but it seems odd that you're using the name `InitialState` for your reducer's state rather than just `State`, so that leads me to be concerned that the contents of the `InitialState` type might not be what you want.

In the snippet you've provided, you're only editing the `translatedSentences` property, so your `State` type can be as simple as:

```
interface State {
    translatedSentences: TranslatedSentence[];
}
```

and your `Action` type is the union:

```
type Action = SET_SENTENCE_TRANSLATION | SET_SENTENCE_TRANSLATIONS;
```

Your reducer should have the signature:

```
const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State
```

and you should not have any problems using `useReducer` with that -- I hope!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response :)